# Copy OpenCV detected faces to a new image

Tags: python, opencv

I've written some code to detect faces in a newspaper image. I am trying to iterate over a list of these found faces, copy them from the image and paste them into a new image.

<clarification per @shortcipher3 comment>
The new image would have the filename across the top and then a mosaic of faces. The code snippet below is actually in a loop that goes through several images.  I want all the new mosaic images to end up as one big image.

Here's my code:

```
pil_img = Image.open(imgfile)
opencvImage = cv.cvtColor(np.array(pil_img), cv.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
gray = cv.cvtColor(opencvImage, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(opencvImage, scaleFactor=1.4, minNeighbors=4, minSize=(30,30))
my_faces = []
for x,y,w,h in faces:
    drawing.rectangle((x,y,x+w,y+h), outline="white")
my_faces.append((x,x+w,y,y+h))
for face in my_faces:
            print(face)
                # roi = i[face[0]:face[1], face[2]:face[3]]
                # cv.imshow('ROI',face)
                # cv.waitKey(0)
            contact_sheet=Image.new('RGB', (600,300))
            contact_sheet.show()
            pil_img.show()
```

The lines commented out, when active, through the following error message:

```
TypeError: 'Image' object is not subscriptable
```

What I really want to do is paste these faces into a new contact_sheet.

Comment: What is the commented "i" variable, also when accessing image array first index corresponds to y, not x. You can do something like --> 
roi = opencvImage[face[2]:face[3], face[0]:face[1]], cv.imshow("ROI", roi), cv.waitKey(0).

Comment: @unlut, commented `i` variable is a `PIL` version of same image, I used it to leverage `pytesseract` on to get text.  I'm actually trying to get the faces from the original image and then paste them into a new image, `contact_sheet`

Answer (score 1):

You could write them in your `for` loop

```
index = 0
for x,y,w,h in faces:
    cv.imwrite(f'face_{index}.jpg', opencvImage[y:(y+h), x:(x+w), :])
    index += 1
```

---

To create a montage from the separate images you can use `feh` if you have it installed:

```
feh -m -O montage.png *.jpg
```

You could also create a montage in pure opencv, for that I recommend first resizing the faces to a uniform size, then creating a a concatenation of them:

```
face_imgs = []
for x,y,w,h in faces:
    face = opencvImage[y:(y+h), x:(x+w), :]
    thumbnail = cv2.resize(face, (100, 100))
    face_imgs.append(thumbnail)
faces = np.concatenate(face_imgs, axis=0)
```

Comment: if I'm reading your code correctly, this will create multiple .jpg images for each face - that's certainly half the battle - I tried the code as is and got `NameError: name 'index' is not defined` so I then tried changing it to `'face_{}.jpg'.format(index)` and got `NameError: 'index' is not defined' even though I have the `index` variable defined above the loop.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify your requirement? You want all the faces pasted to one new image. Is it appropriate for the new image to be the same size as the original, or do you want a Mosaic of the faces that seeks to reduce whitespace?

Comment: I added the second paragraph in the question to answer, the requirement is a new mosaic image that reduces white-space.  Thank you for helping me ask better questions!

Comment: I got your initial answer working - creating the images, thank you. Still working on getting them all back together.  Here's the slightly modified code:
`  for x,y,w,h in faces:
   found_face_file_name = 'face_{}_{}_.jpg'.format(prefix,index)
   cv.imwrite(found_face_file_name, opencvImage[y:(y+h), x:(x+w), :])
   index += 1`